# How to write such query effectively in postgresql: aggregating consecutive rows into arrays(identified by a pair of columns)?

Tags: postgresql

I have a query like:

```
(
    SELECT
        t1.person_id,
        t1.created_at,
        't1' AS type,
        t1.extra_data AS extra_data
    FROM table1 AS t1
)
UNION
(
    SELECT
        t2.person_id,
        t2.created_at,
        't2' AS type,
        t2.extra_data AS extra_data
    FROM table2 AS t2
)
UNION
(
    SELECT
        t3.person_id,
        t3.created_at,
        't3' AS type,
        t3.extra_data AS extra_data
    FROM table3 AS t3
)
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

which will result in something like (`created_at` is a timestamp, and I omit the concrete values, and use simple integers to represent the order)

```
person_id  | type  |  created_at | extra_data
---------  | ----  |  ---------- | ----------
1          | t1    |  9          | a
1          | t1    |  8          | b
2          | t2    |  7          | c
2          | t2    |  6          | c
2          | t2    |  5          | d
1          | t3    |  4          | e
3          | t3    |  3          | f
```

I want to group the consecutive (person_id, type) pairs, with the max `created_at` as the final created_at, and aggregate the `extra_data` into an array, i.e. I want to get the following result:

```
person_id  | type  |  created_at | extra_data_array
---------  | ----  |  ---------- | ----------
1          | t1    |  9          | [a, b]
2          | t2    |  7          | [c, c, d]
1          | t3    |  5          | e
3          | t3    |  4          | f
```

I have tried window functions, but failed to figure out how to achieve this.

My question is:

1) How to write a SINGLE query to achieve my goal?

2) Can such query be fast by using index?

My concern to the second question is that since the base results is selected from a UNION query, I doubt if there is any chance to utilise the index.

Anyone, thanks to all kinds of help!

Answer (score 0):

The two aggregate functions you want are `MAX` and `array_agg`.

I think you'll have better luck applying indexes if you `GROUP` before you `UNION`, so I'd do this:

```
(
    SELECT
        t1.person_id,
        MAX(t1.created_at) AS created_at,
        't1' AS type,
        array_agg(t1.extra_data) AS extra_data
    FROM table1 AS t1
    GROUP BY t1.person_id
)
UNION
(
    SELECT
        t2.person_id,
        MAX(t2.created_at) AS created_at,
        't2' AS type,
        array_agg(t2.extra_data) AS extra_data
    FROM table2 AS t2
    GROUP BY t2.person_id
)
UNION
(
    SELECT
        t3.person_id,
        MAX(t3.created_at) AS created_at,
        't3' AS type,
        array_agg(t3.extra_data) AS extra_data
    FROM table3 AS t3
    GROUP BY t3.person_id
)
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

But you could also `UNION` first and then `GROUP` the result, so long as you `GROUP BY person_id, type`.

A couple more notes:

- This is still going to do a full-table scan on all your tables, since you need to get `created_at` and `extra_data` from every row. It's like the interview question, "What is the time complexity to print the nodes of a binary tree?"
- If you want to order the arrays, you can do that with `array_agg(t1.extra_data ORDER BY t1.created_at)` or whatever. This is where an index might help you.